# Can you define a Vector in MXML?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, vector, mxml

Can you define a vector in MXML?

I have vector property on my class:

```
public var columns:Vector.<Number>;
```

On my class and I want to use in MXML:

```
<MyComponent>
   <columns>
      <Vector>
         <fx:Number>200</fx:Number>
         <fx:Number>300</fx:Number>
         <fx:Number>400</fx:Number>
      <Vector>
   <columns>
<MyComponent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the Vector type:

```
<fx:Vector type="Number">  
    <fx:Number>200</fx:Number> 
    <fx:Number>300</fx:Number> 
    <fx:Number>400</fx:Number> 
</fx:Vector>
```

another example can be found in this [documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5f65f-7ff1.html#WS03d33b8076db57b9626da506121e50da8d4-8000)

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. Thanks